# How WSO2 different than Layer 7 or APIGee?

Tags: api, wso2, middleware, api-manager

I came across features, capabilities of WSO2 as an API management system. I am just interested to know how WSO2 different than Layer 7 or APIGee? (Other than, WSO2 is 100% free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check  this [datasheet](http://wso2.com/resources/data-sheets/api-manager-comparison/) published @ wso2 site.

Comment: This gives high level comparison. Any other details available?